# How to use global prefix for tables in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

New in Laravel. Probably a silly question. I had setup database like this:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'mydb',
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Notice `'prefix' => 'admin'`. This is because I want all tables related to the website's control panel be prefixed with **admin**, e.g: admin_users, admin_log, etc...

But I'm stuck at the very beginning. I'm trying to create migrations via artisan but it's not creating the tables with the prefix.

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

I'm expecting that to create a table named `admin_users`. But it's not.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 19):

Laravel caches config files, so you may simply need to clear the cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

In addition to this, a better practice is to use the `.env` file to define your prefix, like this:

```
...
DB_PREFIX=admin_
...
```

and loading that in your config file, like this:

```
'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', 'abc')
```

This is how it should have been by default.

You're already loading the hostname and port from the `.env` file, so why not do it for the other values as well?

Comment: You are awesome, saved my life, a big thanks Aalaap :)

Answer (score 0):

The migrations will be created without a prefix. After running `php artisan migrate` you should see tables with prefixes

Answer (score 0):

Prefix does not includes underscore (`_`) by itself. In order to create `admin_users` You have to use `admin_` prefix.
When generating migrations You will get plain table names, without prefixes.

With `prefix = 'admin_';` this: `Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {<...>});` will result in creation of `admin_users` table, because Laravel adding Your prefix under the hood by default.

---

**TL;DR**

Even though Your scheme displays table name without prefix, Laravel will create it with prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Schema::connection($name)` method to apply the connection to the schema builder.

For some reason if you just set `connection` property - migration uses this connection to run queries but wont uses it during schema building.

The following is the migration code example that uses `custom` connection to create `foo` table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFoo extends Migration
{
    protected $connection = 'custom';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection($this->connection)->create('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection($this->connection)->dropIfExists('foo');
    }
}
```

This code is tested in real app and works perfectly.

Laravel version: 8.40