# Does Laravel support the use of table prefixes?

Tags: laravel

i set the prefix in config/database and also in .env and as well in phpmyadmin
but when i access my localhost it shows messages that xyz ,abc,(tables name) doesn't exsits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use global prefix for tables in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559209/how-to-use-global-prefix-for-tables-in-laravel-5)

Comment: This is an identical [copy of a question on laracasts.com from 2016](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-table-prefixes-in-laravel) - do the answers there not help? How about [this one here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559209/how-to-use-global-prefix-for-tables-in-laravel-5)?

Comment: yes i find it at laracast but did'not work in my case

Comment: What does `did not work` mean? Describe what you did, describe your problem, show us your code, show us your errors ... You will get a better response here if you read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to configure the table name in the model as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models)

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup table prefix in `config/database.php`,

```
'prefix' => 'myprefix',
```