# Laravel migrations to db_{tables}?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, migrate

Is there a way to migrate, migrations with something before the tablename?

For example I got the tables named roles and users. I want it to migrate to db_roles and db_users. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to rename a table?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559209/how-to-use-global-prefix-for-tables-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

So in the Laravel codebase, you can see that the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` class accepts a database prefix as it's final arguement. This does allow you to add a prefix to the table name.

```
/**
 * Create a new schema blueprint.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @param  string  $prefix
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($table, Closure $callback = null, $prefix = '')
{
    $this->table = $table;
    $this->prefix = $prefix;

    if (! is_null($callback)) {
        $callback($this);
    }
}
```

I have not implemented this practically, but theoretically this how you could do it.